# javascript variables returns strange outputs

Tags: javascript

I'm new here and new to Javascript. I got a strange problem here when I output the values to the console. As far as I know In both these cases the name, and the color is the properties of object car to access them we need to use this.propertyName or object.propertyName, but when I output those values to the console without using this or object name, 1st console.log returns an empty string and the other one returns the uncaught reference error. are they pointing to the window object? then in both the cases, it should return a uncaught reference, can somebody here please clarify this.. thanks in advance. :)

```
var car = {
    name : "ford",
    color:"red",
    log : function(){

         console.log(name);
        // outputs an empty string

         console.log(color); 
        // Returns error (this.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: color is not defined)

    }
}

car.log();
```

Comment: The variables `name` and `color` do not exist in your scope, so JavaScript is looking in the outer and then global scopes for them.  Your `name` is actually referring to `window.name`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't get a `ReferenceError` when outputting `name` is that browsers have a [built-in global called `name`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-name): It's the name of the current window. But they don't have a built-in global called `color`, so you get the error.

To access `name` and `color` on your object when you use `car.log()`, you'd use `this.name` and `this.color`.

Comment: This global `name` is not same as `window.name`, is it? Because if we replace name with window.name in this code we get undefined.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj: Yes, it is, and no, `window.name` won't be `undefined` (provided that's the default `window` global, not something else).

Comment: yeah sorry, you're right. It's `window.name` and it consoles blank string not `undefined`. Thanks :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I really Thank you for your answer. Is there any special purpose for setting window.name to an empty string?

Comment: @seshukumar: It's just the default. The name wouldn't be `""` if it were opened with a link naming it, e.g.: `<a href="..." target="wnd42">...</a>` (the window's name would be `"wnd42"`), or via `window.open` (`window.open("...", "wnd42")`).

Answer (score 4):

Try `console.log(this.name)` and `console.log(this.color)`.

**Additional Information from MDN**

> When a function is called as a method of an object, its this is set to
>   the object the method is called on.
>
> In the following example, when o.f() is invoked, inside the function
>   this is bound to the o object.
>
> Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method)

Comment: I think you mean `this.color`.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are correct both should have thrown uncaught reference but wait ....

actually there is a property on window which is .. yeah ... **name**

so actually you console that property of window.. ie window.name

.. second one is just correct .. uncaught reference